# API /search/excerpts - no answered questions filter

Tags: discussion, api

using the API `/2.2/search/excerpts?answers=0` that means `>=` to 0 answers. I want to search for questions without an answer, I see in some parts of the site the use of `filter=no-answer` but seems to be an internal way to do that... (tried using it, and get results but without data) is there anyway to search for questions without answers `=0` using the API?
or maybe a way to use two filters, no-answer and a custom filter with the data I need to show?

note: I know I can search for no accepted answers, but want for zero answers instead (I could of course query and filter them client side, but interested in a way to do it serverside with the rest of the query params)

Thanks

Comment: I assume the idea is to use /2.2/questions/no-answers... but then I have no excerpts... :(

Comment: iphone app is using the last comment method... but on 2.3...